# `keep_empty_rows` doesn't work in XLSX.jl

Tags: julia

I am trying to use the arg `keep_empty_rows=true` in the XLSX.gettable or XLSX.readtable functions. In both cases, I get an error `got unsupported keyword argument "keep_empty_rows"`.

`keep_empty_rows` is documented in the [API Reference pages](https://felipenoris.github.io/XLSX.jl/stable/api/) for XLSX.jl but doesn't seem to work.

```
for (i, fn) in enumerate(df.fname)
    xf = XLSX.readxlsx(joinpath(pilot_dir, fn))
    for sn in XLSX.sheetnames(xf)
        if (xf[sn]["C2"] == "Good Causes Summary - Catalogue Entry Form")
            println("Processing file ", fn)
            template = DataFrame(XLSX.gettable(xf[sn], "C:N", stop_in_empty_row=false, keep_empty_rows=true))
            push!(CSVrows, readtemplate(template))
        end
    end
end
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The keyword argument works fine for me. (1) The beginning of the question has `keep_empty-rows` instead of `keep_empty_rows`. Make sure a similar typo isn't in the code too. (2) Only the latest release version 0.10 has the `keep_empty_rows` keyword argument. Perhaps your environment has an older version, please show the output of `using Pkg; Pkg.status(; outdated=true)`.

Comment: Status `C:\Users\TGebbels\.julia\environments\v1.9\Project.toml`

⌃ [91a5bcdd] Plots v1.38.16 (<v1.38.17)

⌃ [08abe8d2] PrettyTables v2.2.6 (<v2.2.7)

⌃ [d330b81b] PyPlot v2.11.1 (<v2.11.2)

nothing.

I'm not using these modules.

Comment: The typo in (1) is only in this post. It is not in my code.

Comment: Are you sure you're running the `Pkg.status` in the right environment? `XLSX` is not part of this project at all, based on this output.

Comment: I think I only have one environment. I'm running in VS Code. Here are the top 10 lines of my script: `#using Pkg
#Pkg.add(["DataFrames", "CSV", "Dates", "XLSX", "Printf"])

using Pkg
println(Pkg.status(; outdated=true))

using DataFrames
using CSV
using Dates
using XLSX
using Printf`

Comment: (Sorry I can't format as separate lines!) The `println()` function produces the output I gave before.

Comment: This seems much more suited to a Discourse discussion, please open a thread on the Julia Discourse forum with the code, the `Pkg.status` output, etc.

Comment: Actually, this morning, I tried `Pkg.update()` and lo and behold - it worked! Version 0.9 updated to 0.10 and `keep_empty_rows=true` now works fine. Thank you for your help.